# How to get Phonemes on voice recognition?

Tags: delphi, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, sapi, phoneme

I am working on Voice Recognition to Display the Phonemes and its wave form if possible using the built-in voice recognition on vista and windows 7 using Delphi2009. Other programming languages are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

To get the wave form, you need to enable retained audio using [SetAudioOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718530(VS.85).aspx):

```
m_pRecoCtxt->SetAudioOptions(SPAO_RETAIN_AUDIO, NULL, NULL);
```

Once you have the reco, you can get the audio using [ISpRecoResult::GetAudio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718939(v=VS.85).aspx) and do whatever processiong you need.

For phonemes, I'd look at the answers on your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854087/is-it-possible-to-use-windows-speech-recognition-engine-in-a-word-pronunciation-g).