# How to get phonemes for the word?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

How to get the reference phonemes for the word in Windows Speech Engine using C#? This possible with SAPI 5.3 using  [ISpEnginePronunciation::GetPronunciations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717841%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The .NET wrappers target SAPI 5.1 so this isn't available directly.  You'd have to use the COM interface instead, liable to fail on a machine that boots XP.

Comment: @HansPassant: Hello Hans, Thank you for the comment. I got some kind of "phonemes" using c#. MSDN tells them as "phones/phonemes". Please see the UPDATE section in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746850/finding-pronunciation-correctness/. I really need help, please.

Comment: @HansPassant: I did that code according to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.srgsgrammar.srgstoken.pronunciation(v=office.14).aspx