# Audio Comparison using Micorosft speech recognition engine

Tags: c#, asp.net, speech-recognition, microsoft-speech-platform

I have an application in which user can speak and a word and he will be given the percentage accuracy of the word he spoke. i.e how much clearly the engine recognized the word.

This all works fine ,but i have a dilemma that what words needed to be added to the dictionary which i will give to the recognition engine as dictionary.

If i give words starting with "p" for case pen then words like pendant ,pent etc all will be added to the dictionary.In that case i am not getting the recognized word as "pen".

Instead i always get other words like "pendant" etc

But if i only add limited words to dictionary like "pe","pen" then for the same recorded file i got the recognized words as "Pen" only.

Means it clearly depends on the words which we give to the dictionary.

I have conveyed the same to my client.But what they want is that they can speak wrong words also for a given input words ,so at that time they need not want to get the accuracy and also get the recognized text.

I have done what i could have done for the issue.But my client needs something apart from universe.

Code :

```
public OdllSpeechProcessor(string culture, string speechContent , string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                int counter = 0;
                string line;
                cultureInfo         = new CultureInfo(culture);
                recognitionEngine   = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(cultureInfo);
                words               = new Choices();
                gb                  = new GrammarBuilder();
                gb.Culture          = cultureInfo;
                rndAccuracy         = new Random();

                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line != "")
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < srcContent.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (line.StartsWith(subsetWords, true, cultureInfo))
                            {
                                if (count >= line.Length)
                                {
                                    words.Add(line);
                                    counter++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


                file.Close(); 

                // Adding words to the grammar builder.              
                gb.Append(words);

                // Create the actual Grammar instance, with the words from the source audio.
                g = new Grammar(gb);

                // Load the created grammar onto the speech recognition engine.
                recognitionEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(g);
```

Do any experts have solution for this here? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code.

Comment: Also, I suspect you're using the engine confidence as an estimate of how closely the reference word matches the recognition; that's not always the case (it's very easy to get low-confidence matches that are correct and high-confidence matches that are incorrect).

Comment: @Eric: yes i am using the engine confidence

Comment: Are you using a dictation grammar or a command grammar?  It *sounds* like you're using a command grammar, which isn't the right choice here.   With a command grammar, the engine tries its best to find a match, which can easily result in false positive recognitions.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a command grammar (i.e., a set of choices).  With a command grammar, the engine tries its best to find a match, which can easily result in false positives (as you've seen).  You might want to investigate a dictation grammar, particularly the pronunciation grammar, as I've outlined in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746850/finding-pronunciation-correctness/16805040#16805040).  Note that the solution I outlined uses some interfaces that aren't available in C# (or at least exposed via `System.Speech.Recognition`).